# PHP is_file() not finding files (Code Igniter)

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm using CodeIgniter and from a model I am attempting to check if a view exists.

My code is as follows:

```
$filename = str_replace("models", "", __DIR__)."views/issues/".$vol."~~".$iss."/".$pageName;
if (is_file($filename)) 
    return "issues/".$vol."~~".$iss."/".$pageName;
return false;
```

This returns the proper system file path of: 
/data/www/doc/devappserver/thePage/system/application/views/issues/16~~9/index.htm

However, is_file("/data/www/doc/devappserver/thePage/system/application/views/issues/16~~9/index.htm") returns false.  What's up?

Comment: what are the permissions of the file and the folder?

Comment: I know you have probably checked the spelling of your directory already but just incase, remove the file name from your variable and pass then pass it through is_dir() to make certain you have an acceptable directory.

Comment: Not that this helps in any way, but a tip for the future... You can use the defined constant APPPATH in codeigniter to get the path to the app folder rather than your str_replace.  Also, permissions should not matter.  I just checked and it will work on my server with a file that has 000 permissions and root ownership.

Comment: Thanks for the tip Josh, that's good to know.  Still not sure why this is happening.

Jrod = I've tried file_exists() and is_dir() on the directory as well.  Still returns false.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's better to use file_exists instead of is_file?